# If/Then statements using UISwitch in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to get my app to run one mathematical formula when UISwitch is set to "On" position, and another when it's set to "off" position.

I'm trying to lay it out like this:

if switch = on, then [first formula]

if switch = off, then [second formula]

how would I code this?

=============
EDIT:

This is how I am currently trying to code it.

```
-(IBAction)switchValueChanged:(UISwitch *)sender
{
if(sender.on)
{
-(float)conver2inches: (NSString *)mmeters {
return [mmeters floatValue]/25.4f;
}

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
float answer = [self conver2inches:entry.text];
 output.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",answer];}}

else{
-(float)conver2mmeters:(NSString *)inches {
    return [inches floatValue]*25.4f;
}
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
    float answer = [self conver2mmeters:entry.text];
    output.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",answer];
}}
}
```

Comment: + 1 for a good question, and welcome to SO.

Comment: Start learning basics of programming, then jump into the sea of UI Controls.... conditional, loops, functions etc are most important topics to cover before jumping.

Comment: when i try to build it this way, it says 'conver2inches' and 'conver2mmeters' are undeclared, and that it expects ';' before ':' token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook up a function like this to uiswitch's value changed uievent.

```
-(IBAction) switchValueChanged:(UISwitch *) sender
{
    if(sender.on)
    {
    ...
    }
    else
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *switch;
```

Then:

```
self.switch.on ? [self formula1] : [self formula2];
```

Comment: when i tried to set it up this way, xcode gate me an error: "Expected '=','.',';','asm', or '_attribute_' before '.' token"

Comment: switch might be a bad name for the property since it's a keyword.  Try  `switch1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example of using uiswich on or off in a statement:

```
-(IBAction)onOffSwitch:(id)sender{

if(onOffSwitch.on) {
    // lights on
    [onOffLabel setText:@"Lights Currently On"];
    onOffLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:219.0/255.0 blue:52.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

else {
    // lights off
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [onOffLabel setText:@"Lights Currently Off"];
    onOffLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

}
```

Comment: He's not asking about `switch` but `UISwitch`.

Comment: i tried setting it up like this, and it threw "expected identifier or '(' before "if" and "else"

Answer (score 0):

UISwitch has a [property named on](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISwitch/on) which you can use to detect if the switch is on or off.  Or are you asking how to write code that acts *when* the switch is actually flipped?

Comment: i want to use UISwitch as the true/false operator in my if/then code. if it is set to on, it runs one set of code. if it's off, it runs a different set of code.